# .NET 6.0 JWT token is not recognized from localhost, but it IS recognized through SwaggerUI-- what's up?

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

### Problem

I have a  Target Framework: .NET 6.0 API backend with an exposed API with Identity Framework implemented in it.

I can successfully obtain data 0 issue on unauthorized API Endpoints with this above them on both SwaggerUI AND my localhost frontend.    [AllowAnonymous]

When it comes to authorized API Endpoints however it is a totally different story.

SwaggerUI has NO PROBLEM AT ALL when I put my generated "JWT" into the "Authorize" padlock on the side of the screen.

Localhost JWT are simply not accepted or seen or understood or something I totally don't understand.

### Request seems fine

Screenshot of the API request I am sending over has the authorization with the token, I also took the token to JWT io and it can parse out the name without problem.

I've also tried removing or adding "bearer" to the authorization header sent over and that makes no difference.

Screencap of request:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIxkU.png

### My entire Startup.cs

(I know showing anything less would make it harder for you all to help me so >_< )

---

```
 namespace API
 {
     public class Startup
     {
         public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
         {
             Configuration = configuration;
         }
 
         public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
 
 
         public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
         {
 
             services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(opt =>
             {
                 opt.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
                 opt.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), ServerVersion.AutoDetect(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")), opt => opt.EnableRetryOnFailure());
             });
 
  
             services.AddIdentity<UserModel, IdentityRole>(options =>
 
                {
                    //options.Password.RequiredLength = 5;
                    //options.Password.RequireLowercase 
 
                    options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
                    options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
 
                    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                })
                 .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DbContext>()
                 .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
 
 
 
             services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
             {
                 options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
                 options.Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
             });
 
             services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
             {
                 options.Cookie.Name = "auth_cookie";
                 options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
                 options.LoginPath = new PathString("/api/contests");
                 options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/api/contests");
 
 
                 options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
                 {
                     context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
                     return Task.CompletedTask;
                 };
             });
 
             services.Configure<SmtpSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("SMTP"));
             services.AddSingleton<IEmailManager, EmailManager>();
             services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationPolicyProvider, PermissionPolicyProvider>();
             services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, PermissionAuthorizationHandler>();
 
 
 
             services.AddControllers(opt =>
             {
                 var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
                 opt.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
             });
 
 
             services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new() { Title = "API", Version = "v1" });
                c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Description = "Please insert JWT with Bearer into field",
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
                });
                c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement {
                {
                    new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                    {
                        Reference = new OpenApiReference
                        {
                            Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                            Id = "Bearer"
                        }
                    },
                  new string[] { }
                      }
            });
            });
 
             //Allow localhost to actually contact the server.
             services.AddCors(opt =>
             {
                 opt.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", policy =>
                 {
                     policy.AllowAnyHeader()
                     .AllowAnyMethod()
                     .WithExposedHeaders("WWW-Authenticate")
                     .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:5000", "https://localhost:5000")
      
                     .AllowCredentials();
                 });
             });
 
 
             var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["TokenKey"]));
             services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                 .AddJwtBearer(opt =>
                 {
                     //"Normal" API Auth.
                     opt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                     {
                         ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                         IssuerSigningKey = key,
                         ValidateAudience = false,
                         ValidateIssuer = false,
                         ValidateLifetime = true, //~5 minute leeway?
                         ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero //force time.
                     };
 
                     //SignalR auth.
                     opt.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                     {
                         OnMessageReceived = context =>
                         {
                             var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
                             var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                             if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) && path.StartsWithSegments("/chat"))
                             {
                                 context.Token = accessToken;
                             }
 
                             return Task.CompletedTask;
                         }
                     };
                 }).AddDiscord(options =>
                 {
                     options.CorrelationCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
                     options.ClientId = Configuration["Discord:ClientId"];
                     options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Discord:ClientSecret"];
                     options.Scope.Add("email");
                     //options.CallbackPath = "/";
                 });
 
 
             services.AddScoped<IJwtGenerator, JWTGenerator>();
             services.AddScoped<IUserAccessor, UserAccessor>();
             services.AddScoped<IImageAccessor, ImageAccessor>();
             services.Configure<Infrastructure.Images.CloudinarySettings>(Configuration.GetSection("Cloudinary"));
             services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
             services.AddServiceLayer();
         }
 
 
         // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
         public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
         {
             app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
             app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlingMiddleware>();
             app.UseSwagger();
             app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API v1");
 
                c.DocExpansion(Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.DocExpansion.None);
 
 
 
            });
 
             app.UseCors(c => c.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
 
             app.UseDefaultFiles();
             app.UseStaticFiles();
 
 
             app.UseRouting();
             app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
             app.UseAuthentication();
             app.UseAuthorization();
 
             app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
             {
                 endpoints.MapControllers();
                 endpoints.MapFallbackToController("Index", "Fallback");
             });
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Is that request in the screenshot done through postman or your app? What is the response?

Comment: That screenshot is done through my application, the response was initially a 302 and then a 200 because authentication failed so it redirected as far as I can tell. Postman works no problem but it seems to be depending on these cookies that if I delete postman is blind now too.

.AspNetCore.Identity.Application

Identity.External

Comment: First, I am confused about 'the response was initially a 302 and then a 200'. Can you check with your authentication whether you go into the JWT authentication? Second,  check between your request of postman  and request of using SwaggerUI.